# How to remove backslash in a string in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects, string-formatting

I'm very new to React. I'm trying to remove backslash from a string.

```
[

  {

    "Roll no": 33,
    "Name" : "<p class=\"nameclass\"> \n Rakesh </p>";
 }

]
```

I want to remove slash in a class and and output will be

```
<p class="nameclass">Rakesh</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the data coming from? (It may make sense to clean it up there, after retrieval.)

Comment: There is no backslash character anywhere in the string on the `Name` property in what you've shown. The backslashes you see in the string *literal* are just escapes of the character following them, The string created by that string literal is `<p class="nameclass"> <newline> Rakesh </p>` (with a newline where I have `<newline>`). Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/vf9z6mc4/ (note I had to fix a typo in the code, changing `;` to `,` after the propert value).

Comment: Is it not that what you're looking for? `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "...your Name var" }}>`

Comment: how can i bring this in `class Form extends React.Component {
   
    render() {
        
        return data;
    }
}` Thanks

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: ignore this. The correct answer is provided in the comment by @T.J. Crowder.

It appears you're receiving JSON data via an API.
The data will arrive as a STRING and you can parse it to get an OBJECT.

```
const myJSONData = JSON.parse(response.data)
```

Can you find out how the server "encodes" the data being sent to you? Understanding what is done in that step is critical to being able to "decode" the data back to the original state. The server is probably stringifying the entire structure, but they may be calling encodeURIComponent or doing other processing that you need to be aware of.

Comment: How does this help? The asker hasn't mentioned JSON at all

Comment: It looked like a JSON encoded string, but no - it's just a normal string, surrounded by quotes so the quotes within it get escaped. There is no need to unescape it. The correct answer is to do nothing.

Comment: Apologies for my tone btw. I agree the answer is to do nothing

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression and replace to remove the backlash and \n from your string.

use the following code :

```
let a = "<p class=\"nameclass\"> \n Rakesh </p>";
let n = a.replace(/\n/,"")

output : '<p class="nameclass">  Rakesh </p>'
```

replace will not do changes in the original string, so store the value in a different string.

Comment: The OP didn't ask to remove the new line?

Comment: Please see the output mentioned.

Comment: Besides the new line, `a` already outputs what `n` does.

Comment: yes you are right in saying that.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use replaceAll :

```
string_with_backslash.replaceAll('\\','')
```

This will remove backslashes except for the new line slash(\n).

Comment: The string does not actually contain any backslashes. `"<p class=\"nameclass\"> \n Rakesh </p>".includes('\\') // false`